# back button issue in EDGE browser

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, browser, microsoft-edge

My application's BACK BUTTON  working in chrome and IE but not in EDGE browser.In Jsp page i wrote input button onclick="history.go(-1)"  but it is not working in EDGE.Is there any solution for EDGE browser back navigation  as well as back button issue?i.e->Both the application back button and browser navigation back arrow not working in Edge browser,During my traversal to forward pages when i comeback with below back button or back arrow not working in edge.simple code written in onclick="history.go(-1)".

Comment: does `history.back()` work?

Comment: it is also not working

Comment: history.back() or forward() not working.do you have any urgent solution/replacement of history.go() in EDGE browser

Comment: How on earth shall anybody answer this kind of question? No code, no nothing, should we use a crystal ball?

Comment: <INPUT  type="button" value=<%= bankResourceBean.getBackButton() %>" onClick="history.go(-1)" >

Comment: @Chinmaya please provide additional information by editing the question, instead of commenting on it.

Comment: what additional answer u want?

Comment: can anybody help on this ,it is urgent

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a test with code below. It is working in Edge.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.go(-1);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<aside>
   
     <h1 tabindex="2">Welcome</h1>
    

</aside>
<br>
<a href="www.google.com" onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;"> Go Back</a>
<br> OR <br>
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back 1 Page</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: adding this code in java servlet ,back button issue resolve::-response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1
        response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);Both browser and application back button are working now.:----